# JavaScript changing CSS not working inside of if statement

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation, transform

Here is my html :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="signUpBtn" href="./pages/createaccount.php" onmouseover="rotateBtn()"> Sign up &raquo;</a>
```

Here is the JS... the style changes don't work when I take it out of the if statement. I need the if statement to toggle back and forth between the two rotations.
Doing this to learn, want to use JS and also see how it works with jQuery

```
function rotateBtn() {
var isRotated = 0;
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transformOrigin = "top center";
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transition = "1s ease-in-out";

if (!isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
    isRotated = 1;
} 

if (isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    isRotated = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Teemu My bad, I wasnt aware of it unitl now, thanks for pointing out.. I learnt something new today. will take down my comment.  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use an if else statement, you only need to add a delay between both animation. So you may try this :

*You need to make your element **inline-block** or **block** for the rotation to work.*

```js
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transformOrigin = "top center";
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transition = "1s ease-in-out";

function rotateBtn() {
  document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
  },1000);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="signUpBtn" href="./pages/createaccount.php" onmouseover="rotateBtn()">
     Sign up &raquo;</a>
```

You may also do this using only CSS like this :

```css
#signUpBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#signUpBtn:hover {
  animation: rotate 2s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    ;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="signUpBtn" href="./pages/createaccount.php">
     Sign up &raquo;</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! the setTimeout function worked! I had it working with CSS first, which is probably the most efficient way but I wanted to do it with JS and jQuery for practice :)

Comment: @MelanieMarkarian yes sure, always good to try ;) but i added the CSS so the answer is more complete for new comer :) you want me to add a jQuery one ? or maybe you want to try it by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following code:

```
if (!isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
    isRotated = 1;
} 

if (isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    isRotated = 0;
}
```

After assigning isRotated = 1 in the first if(), the second if() also gets executed because its condition is satisfied.

To avoid this, just include an else statement for the second if()

```
if (!isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
    isRotated = 1;
} 

else if (isRotated) {
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    isRotated = 0;
}
```

Comment: I want  the button to rotate back to where it started, so wouldn't I need that second if statement to execute?

Comment: The second if() is needed, just that an else with it is needed to avoid both the if() statements to get executed together.

Answer (score 0):

how about setting

```
if(isRotated=='0'){
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
    isRotated = 1;
}else if(isRotated=='1'){
    document.getElementById("signUpBtn").style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    isRotated = 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. When I watch the program through the developer tools in Chrome I can see the lines inside of the statement executing, the isRotated variables changes but the CSS changes are not visibly made.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were few more issues; I created a wrapper div added css `transform` on that div. Now it works

```js
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").onmouseover = rotateBtn;
document.getElementById("signUpBtn").onmouseout = unrotateBtn;

function commonStyle() {
document.getElementById("wrapperDiv").style.transformOrigin = "top center";
document.getElementById("wrapperDiv").style.transition = "1s ease-in-out";
}

function rotateBtn() {
commonStyle()
document.getElementById("wrapperDiv").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
}

function unrotateBtn() {
commonStyle()
document.getElementById("wrapperDiv").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
}
```

```css
div {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperDiv">
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="signUpBtn" 
     href="./pages/createaccount.php" >
     Sign up &raquo;</a> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working (partly) but I don't understand why?

Comment: partly? can u elaborate?

Comment: The rotateY(90deg) is working but it isn't going back the other way rotateY(0deg)

Comment: @MelanieMarkarian Updated the code.. this will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use jQuery then,

```
function rotateBtn() {
var isRotated = 0; // boolean value
$("signUpBtn").css("transformOrigin","top center");
$("signUpBtn").css("transition","1s ease-in-out");
    if (!isRotated) {
        $("signUpBtn").css("transform", "rotateY(90deg)");
        isRotated = 1;
    } 

    if (isRotated) {
        $("signUpBtn").css("transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
        isRotated = 0;
    }
}
```